# Making F# Test case methods public for unit testing with Nunit

Tags: f#, nunit

I'm using F# to write my test methods but Nunit complains that the methods are non public.

```
    namespace Test

open NUnit.Framework

type public Test() = 

    [<Test>]
    let testIt () =

        Assert.AreEqual(10,10)
```

what do I need to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put F# test cases in a [module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233221.aspx) to make them public and visible to NUnit:

```
module Tests

open NUnit.Framework

let [<Test>] ``10 should equal 10`` () = Assert.AreEqual(10,10)
```

Answer (score 11):

Since `let` bindings are private to the parent type, you have to use `member` instead:

```
namespace Test

open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
type public Test() = 

    [<Test>]
    member x.testIt() =
        Assert.AreEqual(10, 10)
```

If you don't need complicated setups, using module-level `let` bindings directly should be preferable:

```
module Test

open NUnit.Framework

[<Test>]
let testIt() = Assert.AreEqual(10, 10)
```

Comment: +1 Among much other helpful work, Phan helped us with test cases for [this](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/tree/master/FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning.Tests)